# Acumular puntaje de trivia con Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, switch, alert, vanilla

soy super principiante en js y aún no me meto en esmascript6 (solo aprendí a hacer funciones de flecha). Estoy tratando de hacer un contador de puntos y ya logré que el puntaje se sumara a la variable, el único problema es que no los acumula, sino que simplemente vuelve a sumar uno al cero de la variable puntaje.
Les dejo mi código de principiante

```
var puntaje = 0;

const checkbtn1 = (Option) => {
    switch(Option){
        case 'B1':
            alert("Respuesta correcta")
            puntaje++
            break;
        default:
            alert("Respuesta incorrecta")
    }
}

const checkbtn2 = (Option) => {
    switch(Option){
        case 'A2':
            alert("Respuesta correcta")
            puntaje++
            break;
        default:
            alert("Respuesta incorrecta")
    }
}

const checkbtn3 = (Option) => {
    switch(Option){
        case 'C3':
            alert("Respuesta correcta")
            puntaje++
            break;
        default:
            alert("Respuesta incorrecta")
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: donde estas llamando al valor de puntaje ya que como estas tu codigo deberia funcionar bien, debes colocar un ejemplo minimo verificable

Comment: Biennvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que proveas un [mcve]. Además, intenta explicar con mayor detalle el problema, el comportamiento actual y el resultado esperado. Saludos

Comment: Voy a leer bien el tema del ejemplo mínimo variable. Muchas gracias. De todas formas, el valor del puntaje lo llamo en "var puntaje = 0;" (que está al principio) y cada función es para un HTML distinto. El problema es que me suma pero al pasar a la siguiente hoja de HTML el puntaje vuelve a cero. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

prove tu código y funciona correctamente lo unico que pudiste haber omitido sin darte cuenta es de ejecutar las funciones.

```
let Option = 'B1';
var puntaje = 0;

const checkbtn1 = (Option) => {
     switch(Option){
           case 'B1':
               console.log("Respuesta correcta")
       puntaje++
        break;
    default:
        alert("Respuesta incorrecta")
   }
}

const checkbtn2 = (Option) => {
switch(Option){
    case 'A2':  
        console.log("Respuesta correcta")
        puntaje++
        break;
    default:
        alert("Respuesta incorrecta")
    }
 }
```

asi:

```
checkbtn1(Option); //Primera funcion
Option = 'A2'
checkbtn2(Option) //Segunda funcion

console.log(puntaje)
```

> Si quieres persistir la información deberías guardarla en el LocalStorage del navegador.